# WP_Query not working as expected for attachments and custom meta_query

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

If I use `get_posts()` like so I get a number of results with the value 1 for the `my_key` meta_key:

```
$posts = get_posts( 
    array( 
        'post_type'  => 'attachment', 
        'meta_key'   => 'my_key', 
        'meta_value' => '1' 
    ) 
);

//this has a bunch of results as expected
print_r($posts);
```

However if I create a similar query with WP_Query I get an empty result array

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
       'key'     => 'my_key',
       'value'   => '1',
       'compare' => '=',
       'type'    => 'BINARY'

      )
   )
);

$query = new WP_Query();
$results = $query->query($args);
//this is empty
print_r($results);
```

I have tried a few varieties of the meta_query array all with no luck. I am thinking that this might be a bug, but wanted to make sure I was not missing something first.

Comment: Did you forget the `'` after `value` in your actual code, or is that a WPSE specific typo?

Comment: No, but thanks I was wonder why the code was not formatting.

Comment: What happens if you drop `compare` and `type` completely?

Comment: following @m0r7if3r: what happens if you change BINARY to NUMERIC ?

Comment: Dropping the compare and type does not change the outcome... Numeric is also a no go

Comment: If you do a `print_r()` of the created `WP_Query` instance, it shows you exactly what SQL statement is being generated and gives you an idea what needs to be done to fix the query.

Comment: Not sure where the downvotes came from, this is a legit question (that honestly had me stumped until I loaded the Debug Bar Console and poked at the actual `WP_Query` instance). Try not to take the -1s personally ...

Comment: Thanks. Nothing personal, just kinda strange seeing how things seemed pretty civil here. Oh well. I did take a look at the WP_Query object but was still stumped. I would be interested to understand the logic behind 'inherit' for published attachments...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, just pass your arguments to the constructor of `WP_Query` as this is both cleaner, and the way you're supposed to do it according to the [Codex documentation of the class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You should be constructing things like this:

```
$my_key_query_args = array(
   'post_type'   => 'attachment',
   'post_status' => 'inherit',
   'meta_query'  => array(
       array(
           'key'     => 'my_key',
           'value'   => '1',
           'compare' => '=',
           'type'    => 'BINARY'

      )
   )
);

$my_key_query = new WP_Query( $my_key_query_args );
```

Second, notice the added `post_status` parameter of my array.  By default attachments are added with a post status of "inherit," but `WP_Query` will look for posts with the status of "published," "draft," or "pending."  (See the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters) of that parameter as well).

So there's no bug here, we just forgot to check the defaults for all parameters passed into the object.

There's a note on the "attachment" option for the `post_type` parameter that calls out this requirement:

> The default WP_Query sets `'post_status'=>'published'`, but attachments default to `'post_status'=>'inherit'` so you'll need to set the status to `'inherit'` or `'any'`.

Comment: See my update. This *updated* code is tested to work.

Comment: shouldn't the post_status be publish?

Comment: Default value is publish, but take a look in your database, the post status for *attachments* is "inherit."

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you're trying to use `WP_Query` like `get_posts()`. It seems quite possible that the query is working, but you just can't see the results. `WP_Query` returns a query object that you loop through like this:

```
...
$my_query = WP_Query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

// do your thing

endwhile;
```

Also, note that I used $my_query. I'm a little fuzzy on this, but I believe $query may be a reserved variable from WordPress, and either way, it's often better if you make that query a little-more human-readable (maybe event $attachment_meta_query or something).

Comment: Thanks, but your code is effectively the same as mine. You are just taking a short cut. So this does not solve the problem. I really think we may have a bug on our hands.

Comment: That's not a *shortcut*, but rather the **proper syntax** for invoking a `new WP_Query()`. Pass the `$args` array directly to `WP_Query()`. Also: I strongly recommend using more-descriptive variable names, in order to avoid naming conflicts.